# Bootstrap horizontal stacking of list-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, list

How can I make this look as a horizontal one line/row list seperated as vertical columns (instead of a set of rows with one column, as below) 
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-basic

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

Does it make sense to make use of http://getbootstrap.com/components/#with-button-elements in this case? Or should http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-disabled-links be used instead? I need the border seperation similar to list-group/list-group-item.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set `float: left` to your `li` elements to make it horizontal in one line.

```
ul.list-group:after {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  content: "";
}

.list-group-item {
    float: left;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s2Lr5a8L/)

Also from your given code I believe you don't need to make use of the [#with-button-elements](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#with-button-elements) and [#nav-disabled-links](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-disabled-links). The above example will do just fine.

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't work when I tried it out on a mobile device/small screen

Comment: @LoserCoder Probably because there's no space left to fit another item that's why they go down from each other. You can reduce their padding when on mobile device. Also there's a possibility that you have some styles that loads on mobile device which is causing the issue.

Comment: You can try `display: flex` instead.

Answer (score 29):

Just change your class `list-group` to `list-inline`. Everything else stays the exact same.

Comment: This answer provides a CSS class from Bootstrap 3 so you don't need any custom CSS.

Comment: This does not work in Bootstrap 4.  `list-inline` is meant for arranging `<li>` elements inline without their bullets, not `list-group-item`s.  All of the fancy styling is removed if you use `list-inline`.  See the new [Boostrap docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/typography/#inline).

Answer (score 13):

For Bootstrap 4, replace `list-group` with `d-flex flex-wrap`.

https://jsfiddle.net/rd5my6hf/

Comment: Bootstrap 5.x: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/list-group/#horizontal

Answer (score 11):

easy af (bootstrap 4)

```
.list-group{
     flex-direction: row;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add new class `.list-group-horizontal`:

```
.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item {
    display: inline-block;
}
.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left:-4px;
    margin-right: 0;
    border-right-width: 0;
}
.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius:0;
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
}
.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0;
    border-right-width: 1px;
}
```

Then just use it:

```
<ul class="list-group-horizontal">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

It's based on this gist (imporoved for hide duplicate left/right borders): https://gist.github.com/danielflippance/d6401c926b4fb2442e15

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qfws2gxf/

Comment: Some items also have a `width: `00%` and break the horizontal behavior, so it might also help to include something like `.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item > * {
    width: auto;
}` to start with. Really helped though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`list-inline` works but removes all styling. My solution for bootstrap 4:

```
<ul class="row list-group-horizontal">
   <li class="col-3 list-group-item">
   </li>
</ul>
```