# two separated list-group close to each other [Bootstrap]

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4
    <ul class="list-group listDetail">
        <li class="list-group-item">Name<span class="pull-right">: </span></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Address<span class="pull-right">: </span></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Phone<span class="pull-right">: </span></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Pet Name<span class="pull-right">: </span></li>

    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-8
    <ul class="list-group listDetail">

        <li class="list-group-item">Pete</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Zuma Deluxe Apartement</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">911</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Foo Fighters</li>

    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to bootstrap. So today I made two simple `list-group` using `col-sm-4` and `col-sm-8` inside a modal, I just need to know how to stick both `list-group` 's closely, not separated like this:
[image: separated list-group]

I have searched about `list-group` like this dude [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979850/bootstrap-horizontal-stacking-of-list-group), but he only used one `list-group` and I still have no idea how to solve this.

This noob need a captain here!

Comment: Bootstrap `col-*` contains padding on the both (left and right) sides , you need to remove it.

Comment: You can use custom class for padding-right:0px; or padding-left:0px;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bootstrap you can add `<div class="row"></div>` inside your `<div class="col-*">...</div>`, just like this to achieve what you need :

**See :** https://jsfiddle.net/Lindow/5z4nsesj/

**Here's the code :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
          <div class="row">.col-sm-4
            <ul class="list-group listDetail">
              <li class="list-group-item">Name<span class="pull-right">: </span></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Address<span class="pull-right">: </span></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Phone<span class="pull-right">: </span></li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Pet Name<span class="pull-right">: </span></li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
          <div class="row">.col-sm-8
            <ul class="list-group listDetail">

              <li class="list-group-item">Pete</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Zuma Deluxe Apartement</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">911</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Foo Fighters</li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for enlightening this noob, Captain Lindow!

Comment: @danielpr no worries

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom class for padding-right:0px; or padding-left:0px

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.pad_right{padding-right:0px;}
.pad_left{padding-left:0px;}

</style>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 pad_right" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4
    <ul class="list-group listDetail">
        <li class="list-group-item">Name<span class="pull-right">: </span></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Address<span class="pull-right">: </span></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Phone<span class="pull-right">: </span></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Pet Name<span class="pull-right">: </span></li>

    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 pad_left" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-8
    <ul class="list-group listDetail">

        <li class="list-group-item">Pete</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Zuma Deluxe Apartement</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">911</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Foo Fighters</li>

    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks for adding a new point of view, chander.. But I prefer using Lindow's answer..