# How can I make list-group horizantal in this example?

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am very new to Angular and I practice. I want to sort the list-group elements as I draw them horizontally as in the picture. But when you run the horizontal codes in Bootstrap, it looks like the one on the screen. How can I put list-group elements side by side as I drew

[Horizontal list-group I want to make it alike](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7ZQD.png)

My other codes in app

```
 citycategories : Category2[] = [

    {cityid:1,cityname:"İstanbul",cityprovince:"Başakşehir"},
    {cityid:2,cityname:"İstanbul",cityprovince:"Kayaşehir"},
    {cityid:2,cityname:"İstanbul",cityprovince:"Halkalı"},
    {cityid:2,cityname:"İstanbul",cityprovince:"Halkalı"},
    

   ]
```

```html
<ul class="list-group-horizontal" *ngFor="let city of citycategories">
    <li class="list-group-item">{{city.cityname}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a HTML list appear horizontally instead of vertically using CSS only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145181/how-to-make-a-html-list-appear-horizontally-instead-of-vertically-using-css-only)

Comment: Also [Bootstrap horizontal stacking of list-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979850/bootstrap-horizontal-stacking-of-list-group) for a bootstrap solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the `list-group` class in your `ul` tag. Also, you should probably put the `ng-for` directive on the `li` tag rather than the `ul` tag. In you current set up, you will have 4 lists with 1 item each, when I'm guessing you meant to have 1 list with 4 items.

Code:

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
<li  *ngFor="let city of citycategories" class="list-group-item">{{city.cityname}}</li>
</ul>
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqewag?)

Comment: You're welcome! If you liked the answer it would be really nice of you to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I did it. Sorry for my stack overflow usage:) I'm pretty new here and coding.